How to fix Github Error 403?
I want to push commits in GitHub. The url to the repository is https://github.com/ManuelaCarriero/NeuPipelines.
I used:
git commit -m "my commit" file

then:
git push -u origin main

I got the error:
Username for 'https://github.com': ManuelaCarriero
Password for 'https://ManuelaCarriero@github.com':
remote: Support for password authentication was removed on August 13, 2021.
remote: Please see https://docs.github.com/get-started/getting-started-with-git/about-remote-repositories#cloning-with-https-urls for information on currently recommended modes of authentication.
fatal: Authentication failed for 'https://github.com/ManuelaCarriero/NeuPipelines/'.

I read the answers in StackOverflow and I used
git push

I put my username and then I used a token as password generated in https://github.com/settings/tokens. In this way I do not get anymore this message, however I get the error 403.
manuela@wkrm01:/media/nas_rete/Work_manuela/NeuPipelines$ git push
Username for 'https://github.com': ManuelaCarriero
Password for 'https://ManuelaCarriero@github.com':
remote: Permission to ManuelaCarriero/NeuPipelines.git denied to ManuelaCarriero.
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/ManuelaCarriero/NeuPipelines/': The requested URL returned error: 403

In the discussion in GitHub they suggest to modify "generic credentials" in the control panel in Windows.
This does not seem the solution that works for me because I am using MobaXterm for remote computing. Do you know how can I fix this problem in this case?

Please [edit] your question to show the git URL that you're trying to push to, the exact git command(s) that you're running, and the exact error messages that you're getting. You tagged this with ssh, but 403 is an HTTP error code.

403 stands for Forbidden, means the token you are using does not have Read access . Please review the permissions you gave to that token. One more thing, it that a Classic Token or the new Fine-grained Personal access token?

@AmartyaSinha I used the token generated here https://github.com/settings/tokens.

@Kenster let me know if it is enough...

@HelpNeederStudent Yes, that's where you create a token, but I want to know the exact steps you followed after that, like you chose Classic one of the new Fine-grained, If new Fine-grained, did you give read write access to your repositories through that token? Please provide these details.

One more thing @HelpNeederStudent, avoid adding texts as image. Please paste the text in your question. It will improve the readability.

@AmartyaSinha I wrote all the steps.

@AmartyaSinha I simply copied the generated token and pasted it for Password for 'https://ManuelaCarriero@github.com':. I did not give read write access to my repository through that token.

I am not sure I follow. What kind of permissions does the token have? Show a screenshot with configuration, cut out anything private.

@Destroy666 where can I find this information ?

When you set up/configure the token.

I had this very same 403 problem today when trying to do a git tutorial.
Yes, these days you need to generate the personal access token, which as you say you've already done.
(For interest, some useful instructions on how to do this are here:  add a PAT (Personal Access Token), but to summarise:

From your GitHub account, go to Settings → Developer Settings →
Personal Access Token → Tokens (classic) → Generate New Token (Give
your password) → Fillup the form → click Generate token → Copy the
generated Token, it will be something like
ghp_sFhFsSHhTzMDreGRLjmks4Tzuzgthdvfsrta

Then in your GitHub account, select your token and ensure you have all the necessary permission checkboxes set. When generating a new token these boolean settings all default to OFF:

Click the Update Token button when you are done, then re-attempt your 'git push' command, it should work then.
